OpenPyxl issue while creating Data Validation with Python
I am encountering an issue while using the OpenPyxl library in a Python script.
I am able to create the Data Validation, but when I check the final outcome I can only see my formula (='Loss Level Tree'!$B$64:$G$64) in the cell where the Data Validation Drop Down table should be appearing.
I am able to fix the issue, but manually (which I don't want, that kills the whole purpose of the script), by going into data validation setting and clicking on "apply these changes to all other cells with the same settings". After manually doing this, the final outcome appears correct.
What am I doing wrong in my script?
I've tried using pywinauto / pywin32 libraries to automate the interaction part but no use.
Script (take into account that filename and wbook have been removed for safety purposes):
    filename = X
    wbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'Y)
    sheet = wbook["Count BO"]

    validation_t = DataValidation(type='list', formula1='"={0}!$B$64:$G$64"'.format(quote_sheetname('Loss Level Tree')), allow_blank=True, showErrorMessage=False, showDropDown=False)
    sheet.add_data_validation(validation_t)
    validation_t.add('T2:T1048576')

    wbook.save(r'E:\file)




Why with the single and double quotes around your formula? Just use single quotes (or just use double quotes, but not both) validation_t = DataValidation(type='list', formula1='={0}!$B$64:$G$64'.format(quote_sheetname('Loss Level Tree')), allow_blank=True, showErrorMessage=False, showDropDown=False)

Hi Moken, how are you? I´ve tried using only single quotes where you mention but when i run the script in the Source: part of Data Validation i have the "='Loss Level Tree'!#REF!" issue. when i use my way it appears correctly "='Loss Level Tree'!$B$64:$G$64". The issue is, as i mentioned before, that the data validation has to be opened and click "ok" for it to appear or else the formula appears in the cell.

With a Workbook containing two Sheets, "Count BO" and "Loss Level Tree", where the "Loss Level Tree" Sheet holds the datavalidation values in cells B64:G64 the following code works for me.
That is your code with 'validation_t' value modified as suggested in the earlier comment. This line is in the code under the comment '### Modified to use single quotes'
However there is no need to use the string formatting, just use a normal string as shown under '### Modified to use string'
I don't know why the range is returning #REF since it should exist populated or not, but you can try using a normal string. If you need to create the reference from a variable, these days you'd use an f string.
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl.utils import quote_sheetname


# filename = X
wbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
sheet = wbook["Count BO"]

### Original
# validation_t = DataValidation(type='list', formula1='"={0}!$B$64:$G$64"'.format(quote_sheetname('Loss Level Tree')), allow_blank=True, showErrorMessage=False, showDropDown=False)

### Modified to use single quotes
# validation_t = DataValidation(
#    type='list', 
#    formula1='={0}!$B$64:$G$64'.format(quote_sheetname('Loss Level Tree')), 
#    allow_blank=True,    
#    showErrorMessage=False, 
#    showDropDown=False
#    )

### Modified to use string
validation_t = DataValidation(
    type='list', 
    formula1="'Loss Level Tree'!$B$64:$G$64",
    allow_blank=True, 
    showErrorMessage=False, 
    showDropDown=False
    )

sheet.add_data_validation(validation_t)
validation_t.add('T2:T1048576')

wbook.save('foo_out.xlsx')

